# Problem posted data with jQuery submit()

Tags: forms, jquery

I have the script below. I am trying to POST the data and insert it into a database, the jQuery executes just fine, but does not post anything, the action is working properly because when i post the data without the script, the data posts fine and is inserted into the database fine without any errors, so it seems as if the jquery function is posting nothing. can someone please help?

```
$('#form').live('submit',function(){
  $('#form').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#div').append("<h2>submittes</h2>");
  return false;
  });


<form id="form" method="post" action="execute.php" name="form">
<textarea id="text" name="update"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="update" id="update-submit">
</form>
```

EDIT:

```
$('#form').live('submit',function(){
var updateTextArea = $('#textarea').val();
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "execute.php",  
  data: updateTextArea,  
  success: function() {  
  $('#form').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#div').append("<h2>updated</h2>");
  }
  });
  return false;
  });
```

this is what i have for the ajax, but i am still not having any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any AJAX calls in your javascript. You're just fading out the form, appending an `h2`, and preventing the default action from occurring (which would be to submit the form normally).

Here's a basic example of how to create a POST ajax request:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), { update: $(this).find('#text).val() }, function(){
    // success
  });
});
```

Checkout the jQuery API/Docs for more info on this. There are also dozens of tutorials lurking around the net on how to do this.

Comment: k, well i did try creating an ajax function and sending the data over, but my action page is looking for a post variable named update, how can i make sure that the variable is sent over with the name update

Comment: thanks, ill look into the post function as well. thanks ill try this out really quick.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by returning `false` from the event handler function, you trigger two things:

- prevent the default action (`.preventDefault()`)
- stop the event propagation (`.stopPropagation()`)

This prevents that the submit ever happens.

You need to transfer the data on your own within the submit event handler. For instance, create an ajax request which serializes the form data and sends it to your server.

Could look like:

```
$('#form').live('submit',function(){
  $('#form').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#div').append("<h2>submittes</h2>");

  $.post('execute.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      // do something after success
  });
  return false;
});
```